# Defining attributes in abstract Class is good or bad

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Is it a good design to define attributes in abstract class and use it like below.
For example

```
abstract class Base {
    @Getter
    private String name;

    protected Base(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
}



class Derived extends Base {
    public Derived() {
        super("name");
    }
}
```

Should I put attribute name is inside base class or should I put it in the derived class. Which one is a good design and how to decide that.

Comment: Abstract *methods* don't have attributes.

Comment: Hi @Andreas abstract methods can have attributes in java as I defined above. Not only attributes but also concrete methods too.

Comment: 1) There are _constructors_ in the code snippets which cannot be abstract as opposed to _methods_. 2. The question where to put field `name` does not have "good"  or "bad" answer.

Comment: @pradeepkalra Abstract *classes* can have attributes (aka properties aka fields). Abstract *classes* can have abstract *methods*. Abstract *methods* don't have attributes. Please keep your terminology straight. --- The first line of the question says it right, but the question title doesn't.

Comment: Sorry got it. It was a typo thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, you are confused with your terms. I think you are talking about abstract *classes*, not abstract methods.

To answer your question: There's really no hard and fast rule about whether it is better to have "attributes" / variables in a base class or not. Sometimes it is unavoidable, like in the case where you are extending a concrete class with abstract methods

Comment: Hi, Do you think it would be great if I have some complicated calculations in derived class which actually needs the attribute of base class. I mean it would look too messy to fetch an attribute name by getName() in the derived class everytime I would like to perform a big complicated operation.